# Angelika Langer GenericsFAQ - Can i use raw type as any other type?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading through documentation of [AgelikaLangerDoc](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20use%20a%20raw%20type%20like%20any%20other%20type?). I have just started reading
this article. I have seen the following syntax in the code.

```
interface Copyable<T>{
  T copy();
}

final class Wrapped<Elem extends Copyable<Elem>>{
}
```

I am not able to understand the following generics syntax meaning.

```
<Elem extends Copyable<Elem>>
```

I know its pretty basic but really generics is tricky. Why do we need to put it like this?
We could have said something ike

```
final class Wrapped<Copyable<Elem>>{
}
```

I know its not legal but even the above syntax is not easy to understand. Can someone
explain this part?

Comment: `Elem` is the type parameter, and we are asserting that it must implement `Copyable<Elem>`.

Comment: "Wrapped<Elem extends Copyable<T>>" this isn't what Angelika Langer wrote. It wouldn't compile, She wrote "Wrapped<Elem extends Copyable<Elem>>"

Comment: @Puce i have corrected the error.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I don't think that question is relevant here. It's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @RohitJain I think it's relevant in the sense that it explains the principle the OP is asking about.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup i have gone through the question and that is not really what i am asking. Rohit is correct.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup. OP is talking about generic type declaration. PECS is somewhat related to instantiating the generic type. Both have different concepts.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for the noise then :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration:

```
class Wrapped<Elem extends Copyable<Elem>>
```

simply says that you can only instantiate `Wrapped` type with a subtype of `Copyable`. Note the `Elem` part. It means that the subtype `Elem` should be a subtype of `Copyable<Elem>`.

For e.g., suppose you have a class that implements that generic interface:

```
interface Copyable<T>{
    T copy();
}

class CopyableImpl implements Copyable<CopyableImpl> {
    CopyableImpl copy() { ... }
}
```

Now you can instantiate the `Wrapped` generic type with `CopyableImpl` like this:

```
Wrapped<CopyableImpl>
```

Replace `CopyableImpl` with `Elem` and see whether it satisfies the declaration.

```
CopyableImpl extends Copyable<CopyableImpl>
Elem extends Copyable<Elem>
```

So, it is a valid type argument for `Wrapped`.

---

However, if your class is something like this:

```
class SomeCopyable implements Copyable<OtherCopyable> {
    OtherCopyable copy() { ... }
}
```

you cannot instantiate `Wrapped` generic type with this class, since it does not satisfy the type parameter for `Wrapped`.

```
SomeCopyable extends Copyable<OtherCopyable>
Elem extends Copyable<Elem2>  // Elem 2 is different from Elem
```

---

As for your proposal:

```
class Wrapped<Copyable<Elem>>
```

no this declaration is completely different from the original one. Considering the fact that generic types are invariant, in the sense, a `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<CharSequence>` even though `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence`. So, for this declaration, you can only instantiate the `Wrapped` type with `Copyable` type argument like this:

```
Wrapped<Copyable<String>>
Wrapped<Copyable<Integer>>

Wrapped<CopyableImpl>  // Wrong. This doesn't match the type declaration.
```

---

### Further Reading:

- [Angelika Langer - How do I decrypt `"Enum<E extends Enum<E>>"`?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#How%20do%20I%20decrypt%20Enum?)

Comment: what is the use of doing something like this class CopyableImpl implements Copyable<CopyableImpl> {
    CopyableImpl copy() { ... }
}i am still confused a lil about it. I am really finding deciphering generics pretty tricky.

Comment: @benz. If you are dealing with some generic type, which works on the type that implements it, then that type would need to be given as type parameter. For example - consider - `Comparable<T>`, if you want a class to be comparable, you would declare it as: `class Test implements Comparable<Test>`.

Comment: @benz. Well as for deciphering, trust me I was bad at generics few months back. It's only that site - AngelikaLanger's, which made be feel quite confident about it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time Rohit. I am sure because i am just entering to this field. Finding things pretty tricky. :) hopefully i will be able to benefit from all knowledge you guys have.