# Angelika Langer Enum<E extends Enum<E>> decoding

Tags: java, generics

As per my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444652/angelika-langer-genericsfaq-can-i-use-raw-type-as-any-other-type), I am reading the article from [Angelika Dissecting Enum](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#How%20do%20I%20decrypt%20Enum?). Except for the points that a type can only be instantiated for its subtypes and the subtypes do inherit some common methods, I am not able to understand the article.

1. What is the meaning of abstract Enum class declared in this way? How is it helpful?
2. The document in the last part has described three aspects, can someone explain them in easier terms to me?
3. I do see in the code sketch the Enum class is declaring the `compareTo` method. When Enum is implicitly implementing `Comparable interface`. Why do it needs to define its own `compareTo` method?
4. Seems like it is a concept of recursive generics. What does recursive generics exactly mean? After doing a bit of R&D and understanding my last question answer, I understand that it forces the class to be parameterized on itself.

Still, a detailed explanation would be useful.

Comment: "Why didn't it say something like..." - because that's not valid Java ;)

Comment: Honestly speaking my emphasis is not that. I know its not valid java. My point is to understand the whole concept @OliCharlesworth

Comment: In C++ the idiom is known as [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). See also the following page for a reference to Java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @nosid: except that in Java it is not useful. (neither is it safe in C++)

Answer (score 2):

I think the main benefit of declaring generic types as `Type<E extends Type<E>>` is that such generic classes will make subclasses to inherit methods which return or accept arguments with subtype's type. Such methods in `java.lang.Enum` are:

```
public final int compareTo( E o) { ... }
public final Class< E > getDeclaringClass() { ... }
```

So, if we declare the enum `Color`, that implicitly means:

```
public class Color extends Enum<Color>
```

so in this instantiation of `Enum` the type paramater `E` is assigned the type argument `Color`, so the above methods will look like these:

```
public final int compareTo(Color o) { ... }
public final Class<Color> getDeclaringClass() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Katona, i understood the concept after thoroughly reading. thankyou very much. Still i am looking for point 2 and 4 clarification.

Comment: Everything you say here applies equally if it's declared as `class Type<E>`

Comment: @newacct you are right, but with `class Type<E extends Type<E>>` you can force that `E` can only be the type of the subclass. So, while `class Type<E>` allow `class Sub extends Type<String>` `class Type<E extends Type<E>>` allows only `class Sub extends Type<Sub>>`.

Comment: @Katona: No it doesn't, because you can then have `class AnotherSub extends Type<Sub>`

Comment: @newacct Indeed, I missed that. I still believe my point is valid, this pattern is useful when you want to enforce that the type of subclasses or implementations appear as arguments or return values of functions, though it's not perfect, it can be abused as you pointed out.

Comment: @Katona: You should only specify bound if you need to make use of the specific constraint that the bound specifies. There are some cases where a declaration like `Type<E extends Type<E>>` really makes use of its bound, but it's rare. But most times, the bound can be removed and it would still compile, meaning that the bound was not needed for type safety.

Comment: @newacct Honestly, now that we have this discussion, I have doubts about the usage of this construct. :)

Answer (score 0):

When saying something like `Enum<Color extends Enum<Color>>`, that sounds like you are declaring a generic type parameter `Color` that makes sure that it extends `Enum` with a type parameter matching `Color`.

But that isn't where generic type parameters for a class are declared.  You must declare them next to the class name; you can only use them later in the `extends` clause.  E.g.

```
//                Use "extends" here  ...                   not here.
public class MyClass<E extends MyClass<E>> extends MySuperClass<E>
```

In this example, you are declaring the *class* `Color` to be the value of the generic type parameter that is already defined on `Enum`.